# how to get values in jquery foreach inside the foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a json response containing one array, inside that array I have one more array.

My AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: { city: city, priceRange: range },
  url: "rentpriceRangeFilter.php",
  success: function(data) {
    var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data); // convert the json
    console.log(res);
    if (res['status'] == 1) {
      var htmlString = '';
      $.each(res['data'], function(key, value) {
        console.log(key + ' is ' + value.house);
      });
    }
  },
});
```

rentpriceRangeFilter.php (I return the json response)

```
echo json_encode(array("status"=>"1","response"=>"success","data"=>$mainArray));
```

My JSON response like this:

```
{
  "status": "1",
  "response": "success",
  "data": [{
    "id": "2",
    "house": "1 BHK Apartment for Lease",
    "rentLease_amount": "6000000",
    "furnished_type": "Semi-Furnished",
    "CreatedOn": null,
    "Rent": "60 Lac",
    "multipleImages": [{
      "imageId": "3",
      "rentImageId": "2",
      "rentImageName": "2cf011438e6cd43c6bfaa6cac653d86e.jpg"
    }, {
      "imageId": "4",
      "rentImageId": "2",
      "rentImageName": "e2c5be420130370c5118120a1bc749c6.jpg"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": "1",
    "house": "1 BHK Aparatment for Marathahalli",
    "rentLease_amount": "500000",
    "furnished_type": "Fully-Furnished",
    "CreatedOn": null,
    "Rent": "5 Lac",
    "multipleImages": [{
      "imageId": "1",
      "rentImageId": "1",
      "rentImageName": "7d2905c30ab211732b97dbf165c75526.jpg"
    }, {
      "imageId": "2",
      "rentImageId": "1",
      "rentImageName": "bcf6cb343aaa2cc8e50ff52baa062bcc.jpg"
    }]
  }]
}
```

Now I want to display `house` name and `multipleImages` values, but in my ajax page I can get only house name, I don't how to display the `multipleImages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another loop on `multipleImages` like below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {city:city,priceRange:range},
    url: "rentpriceRangeFilter.php",
    success:function(data){
        var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);// convert the json
        console.log(res);

        if(res['status']==1){
            var htmlString='';
            $.each( res['data'], function( key, value ) {
                console.log(key + ' is ' + value.house);
                $.each( value.multipleImages, function( key2, image ) {             
                    console.log('imageId of ' + key2 + ' is ' + image.imageId);
                    console.log('rentImageId of ' + key2 + ' is ' + image.rentImageId);
                    console.log('rentImageName of ' + key2 + ' is ' + image.rentImageName);
                });
            });
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageId' of undefined

Comment: @@ Mohammad Hamedani, i tried your code i am getting error

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked, please accept this answer. @subikshanM

Answer (score 0):

You can loop again through your properties :

Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating the solution : https://jsfiddle.net/equbq6rf/

```
const data = [{
    "house":"My house",
    "multipleImages":[{
        "imageId":1,
        "rentImageId":2,
        "rentImageName":"image_name.jpg"
    },{
        "imageId":3,
        "rentImageId":4,
        "rentImageName":"image_name2.jpg"
    }]
},{
    "house":"My house number 3",
    "multipleImages":[{
        "imageId":5,
        "rentImageId":6,
        "rentImageName":"image_name3.jpg"
    },{
        "imageId":7,
        "rentImageId":8,
        "rentImageName":"image_name4.jpg"
    }]
}];

 $.each(data, (key, value) => {
   console.log(key + ' is ' + value.house);
   $.each(value['multipleImages'], (imageKey, imageValue) => {
    Object.keys(imageValue).forEach((property) => {
        console.log(imageValue[property]);
    });
   });
 });
```

You can push it further but it should do the trick.

Hope it helps :)

Dylan